# Reading in a text file more 'intelligently'

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, file-io, input

I have a text file which contains a list of alphabetically organized variables with their variable numbers next to them formatted something like follows:

```
aabcdef           208
abcdefghijk       1191
bcdefga           7
cdefgab           12
defgab            100
efgabcd           999
fgabc             86
gabcdef           9
h                 11
ijk               80
...
...
```

I would like to read each text as a string and keep it's designated id# something like read "aabcdef" and store it into an array at spot 208.

The 2 issues I'm running into are:

1. I've never read from file in C#, is there a way to read, say from
   start of line to whitespace as a string? and then the next string as
   an int until the end of line?
2. given the nature and size of these files I do not know the highest ID value of each file (not all numbers are used so some
   files could house a number like 3000, but only actually list 200
   variables) So how could I make a flexible way to store these
   variables when I don't know how big the array/list/stack/etc.. would
   need to be.

Comment: You can use something like into an array. string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines("name"); and String.Split to split each line into multiple parts.

Comment: Unless you specifically need an array, consider storing the values in a `Dictionary<string, int>` -- or a `Dictionary<int, string>`, depending on whether you need to access by id or by string.

Comment: Is the line format fixed-position or white-space delimited? What encoding is used for the file?

Comment: Do you know what is the maximum number that you can encounter in this file ?

Comment: no. it varies for each file and is inconsistent. one file the max value was 33989, one it was 600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about how I would improve other answers and I've found this alternative solution based on `Regex` which makes the search into the whole string (either coming from a file or not) safer.

Check that you can alter the whole regular expression to include other separators. Sample expression will detect spaces and tabs.

At the end of the day, I found that `MatchCollection` returns a safer result, since you always know that 3rd group is an integer and 2nd group is a text because regular expression does a lot of checking for you!

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("djdodjodo\t\t3893983");
builder.AppendLine("dddfddffd\t\t233");
builder.AppendLine("djdodjodo\t\t39838");
builder.AppendLine("djdodjodo\t\t12");
builder.AppendLine("djdodjodo\t\t444");
builder.AppendLine("djdodjodo\t\t5683");
builder.Append("djdodjodo\t\t33");

// Replace this line with calling File.ReadAllText to read a file!
string text = builder.ToString();

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"([^\s^\t]+)(?:[\s\t])+([0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

// Here's the magic: we convert an IEnumerable<Match> into a dictionary!
// Check that using regexps, int.Parse should never fail because
// it matched numbers only!
IDictionary<int, string> lines = matches.Cast<Match>()
                                    .ToDictionary(match => int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value), match => match.Groups[1].Value);

// Now you can access your lines as follows:
string value = lines[33]; // <-- By value
```

### Update:

As we discussed in chat, this solution wasn't working in some actual use case you showed me, but it's not the approach what's not working but your particular case, because keys are "[something].[something]" (for example: `address.Name`).

I've changed given regular expression to `([\w\.]+)[\s\t]+([0-9]+)` so it covers the case of key having a dot.

It's about improving the matching regular expression to fit your requirements! ;)

### Update 2:

Since you told me that you need keys having any character, I've changed the regular expression to `([^\s^\t]+)(?:[\s\t])+([0-9]+)`.

Now it means that key is anything excepting spaces and tabs.

### Update 3:

Also I see you're stuck in .NET 3.0 and `ToDictionary` was introduced in .NET 3.5. If you want to get the same approach in .NET 3.0, replace `ToDictionary(...)` with:

```
Dictionary<int, string> lines = new Dictionary<int, string>();

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
      lines.Add(int.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value), match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Does this assume each line has an equal ammount of spaces / tabs between text and integer? as it stands that is not the case, the spaces vary based on length of the text (don't ask me why the customer would set these up that way)

Comment: @DarthSheldon This regex does assume nothing more than tabs and spaces are column separators: `[\t\s]+` is "one or more of these characters". This is why my answer says you can add any other separator in that regex to fit your needs, but it assumes 1 or more occurrences of one or more separators specified in the whole expression.

Comment: @DarthSheldon I hope it will work as expected. I did my testing in a console app (I've just pasted here the working code) and it seems that it should work in your actual case too

Comment: @DarthSheldon Finally, have you tried this approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54660/discussion-between-darthsheldon-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Comment: @DarthSheldon Check my update, the approach works. I've tried the file you provided in our chat. It was about improving the regular expression to detect keys with dot!

Comment: Looks like this works great! the issue of ToDictionary was the problem

Comment: @DarthSheldon Nice, I'm glad it worked finally! Now I give you the legacy to improve the approach! :)

Answer (score 5):

Basically you need a `Dictionary` instead of an array or list. You can read all lines with `File.ReadLines` method then split each of them based on space and \t (tab), like this:

```
var values = File.ReadLines("path")
    .Select(line => line.Split(new [] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .ToDictionary(parts => int.Parse(parts[1]), parts => parts[0]);
```

Then `values[208]` will give you `aabcdef`. It looks like an array doesn't it :)

Also make sure you have no duplicate numbers because `Dictionary` keys should be unique otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: There's an assumption there that there is simply a single character (a space or tab) between the two columns

Comment: I would rename `x` on `ToDictionary` to also `line`!

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer good point, naming is important even for lambda variables :) I have changed it to parts that makes more sense to me since it is an array of strings instead of a single line

Comment: yes there are no duplicate numbers (but some duplicate texts) in the files so this sounds like it will work, the only issue is that there is more than just one space between words and id number. it's more like 40 or 50, depending on the length of text

Comment: @DarthSheldon spaces doesn't matter.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries will remove the empty strings.

Comment: @Selman22 did you test your own sollution before posting? It is not operating in anyway how you've described, it just fills the dictionary in order as they are received, so it does not help me

Comment: @Selman22 yeah, that proves my point. {12,cdefgab} should be at the 12th spot in the dictionary, not the 3rd

Comment: no it doesn't...this is not an array and dictionary hasn't an order. if you want to sort them use `values = values.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value); `

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. I did not realize it wouldn't be sorted when inspecting in Debugger